# Jquery works fine on jsFiddle but not on localhost

Tags: jquery, html

i have a code on jsfiddle which works fine 
here is the link
[Jsfiidle code](http://jsfiddle.net/79psrru8/1/)

but when i try to run the code on my machine the jquery is not working..

```
  <html><head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .custom-dropdown {
    position:relative;}

    .custom-dropdown .table-wrapper {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:21px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    overflow-x:hidden;}
    .custom-dropdown .dropdown-table {
    width: 300px;}</style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown-table').searchable({
        striped: true,
        searchType: 'fuzzy'
    });

    $(".dropdown-search").bind("keyup", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $table = $this.next();
        if ($this.val().length > 0 && $table.is(":hidden")) {
            $table.show();
        } else {
            $table.hide();
        }

        var resultCount = ($table.find("tr:visible").length - 1);
        $table.find(".search-result-counter").html(resultCount + " records found.");
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="custom-dropdown">
    <input type="search" id="search" value="" class="dropdown-search" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="dropdown-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        <span class="search-result-counter"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>ccc</td>
                    <td>Some</td>
                    <td>More</td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this program works on jsfiddle but when i run this onmy computer jquery has no effect 
please help

Comment: In fiddle you are using jQuery version **1.11.0**, check if changing that in your code helps

Comment: What for do you include jQuery twice?

Comment: When you say "on my computer", are you referring to a local web server or just a file?

Comment: I think you have not included ``jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js``

Comment: You have multiple jQuery references

Comment: @SameerK yesss ..  Thanks,, it works fine after including jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Below are the mistakes I found in your code

- Missing searchable plugin
- Jquery version is very old/different versions of jquery library included

  Remove the other jquery library inclusions and add the below code

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgithub.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/master/dist/jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeahh .. thankxx... dude.. it works for me after adding jquery  searchable plugin :)

Comment: Using old jQuery version is not a mistake - just a bad practise. While, for example. including jQuery twice, especially between other scripts, really can cause problems.

Comment: @Regent Agreed. Using old version is not a mistake. Just a bad practice. Anyway including searchable plugin solved his issue.

Comment: @DonX what about editing answer, pointing out that there is mistake/problem in not adding _searchable_ plugin script and having suggestion to use newer version of jQuery?